# How to remove extra space from the top of the Table View in iPhone X using Objective C iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, iphone-x

I have already developed an app in Objective C which is working fine in all the iPhone mobiles. But when I am running this app in iPhone X Simulator then I dont know how I am getting some extra space (about 20-22 pixels) in the top of the UITableView. I tried all this solutions, but none of the below helped me :

```
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.tableView.bounds.size.width, 0.01f)];

self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;

[tblProducts setSectionHeaderHeight:0];

self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return CGFLOAT_MIN;
}
```

I know this can be possible by setting my table view contentInset like :

```
tblProducts.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(-30, 0, 0, 0);
```

Is there any other solution to resolve this issue for iPhone X?

I checked my table view frame in ViewDidLoad, It's (0, 64, WIDTH, HEIGHT), Is there any problem with Status bar?

Please suggest me. Thank you in Advance!

Comment: Did you set proper launch screen of iPhone x

Comment: @iPatel No, I haven't set iPhone x launch screen.

Comment: Please set it first  1125px × 2436px

Comment: Okay done @iPatel

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can try setting `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` property to `Never`.

In Swift, I have this in `UICollectionView`:

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
}
```

In Objective-C, the same applies to `UITableView`, set it like so:

```
if (@available(iOS 11.0, *)) {
    [_tableView setContentInsetAdjustmentBehavior: UIScrollViewContentInsetAdjustmentNever];
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If Anyone is looking for answer with storyboard then select your UITableView in storyboard and just change the content inset to never, like shown in below link

[image]

Comment: @HarshadPatel - Glad it helped. Welcome

Answer (score 0):

You can set tableview style grouped to plain it will remove extra space or you can set one property to your Viewcontroller is

self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars = true