# How to move a table content to the top of the screen?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift4, xcode9

I am still new to iOS and Swift and I am using Swift4 and Xcode9 to edit an iOS project which is made with a prior versions of Xcode and Swift (Xcode8 and Swift3). In the project there is a TableViewController used. So the problem is when I open the project in Xcode9 and run it, it shows some space on the top. I tried changing y values, but didn't work. My questions are,

1. How to solve the upper mentioned problem. (There is a question like this in Stack Overflow already. But it's not due to different Xcode version. But I even tried all the suggestions in the answers. But none of them worked for me.)
2. When there is a text label or something on the top of the table content, I can remove that space, from the top, but it goes to in between that label and the table added. And the label is unable to get a click action or something when it's moved to the top. How to solve that?

Any suggestion/ answer will be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: select your controller , and click on yello icon on top , in attribute inspector look for automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets and uncheck it if it's checked.

Comment: @TusharSharma automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets is already unchecked.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46639988/3231194 might help.

Comment: Do you use the method "estimatedHeight" in tableview?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
 if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
    yourTableView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But this may work for UICollectionView. I don't have a UICollectionView . What I have is a UITableView.

Comment: I fixed using this snippet in UITableView. It has nothing to do with collection or table. It’s the property of UIScrollView for which both table and collection are subclasses

Comment: Sorry, I found your answer is almost correct, but it moves the content to the top of the screen, which means to the navigation row level. Then the first row hides behind the navigation row. I am glad if you have a solution to that as well.

Comment: uncheck the Under Top bars by selecting view controller in storyboard in attributes inspector and add your table with top constraint as Zero

Comment: I didn't get what you meant, could you please explain that a bit more or add a a screen?

Comment: Go to your viewcontroller on storyboard, select viewcontroller, and go to attributes inspector, then uncheck the option  **Under Top Bars**.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm going to attempt to answer your question but I wasn't totally positive since you didn't include any code or screenshots.

Firstly. If you mean that there seems to be a gap between where the tableView starts and where the first cell is displayed, this is correct. You can fix that by doing:

```
tableView.contentInset = .zero
```

this means that any content inside the `tableView` starts goes all the way to the edges.

Now for the label receiving touches. You want to look at user interaction enabled values on the storyboard:

[image]

Whenever you have views that stack on top of each other, the view UNDER will not receive touches if the view on top has user interaction enabled. If you want a touch to bleed through another view you either can

1) avoid the issue by not stacking views on top of each other (often unavoidable, like putting a label on a view and wanting the background view to do something)

2) turn off the user interaction on the view on top so the view on bottom gets the touch

Comment: Sorry, I have no rights to add screenshots or source code. And I think source code is not necessary for this. But even if so, I am unable to add those. Anyways the answer you gave doesn't work in my case, but thanks for the attempt, it's a well prepared answer.

Answer (score 1):

tableView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.zero, animated: true)

this code will move

Comment: Thank you for the attempt, but this doesn't work in my case.